# BlockChain: Always get a new Hash

Tags: blockchain

I am asking a simple question. Why we say that we would always get a new hash in a blockchain? Why we can't have collisions?

One way of collision is that the hard disk becomes full and there is no more space to store a transaction.

Some body please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1):

Blockchain uses a cryptographic hash function that is designed to have [collision resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistance).  Thus, while it's *possible* you might run into a pair of inputs that produce the same output... it's very very unlikely to happen by chance; and it is believed to be very difficult to intentionally find such a pair of inputs.

Disk space has nothing to do with collisions in the hash function.

Comment: Hashes are linked to each other. For each block we have a hash value. Suppose we get a Hashvalue for a block but there is no disk space. Then we use a brand new harddisk to store that block. How will we link two blocks on different harddisks?

Comment: @user2994783, that's not how Bitcoin (or other blockchains) work, and in any case, it's a separate question that should be asked separately (but probably would be best to ask on the Bitcoin Stack Exchange site).